# How to get Column name in exception for constraints violation in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, constraints

I have constraints over currency field that negative value is not acceptable. Constraints is all working fine and I am getting error when constraints violated as per below.

> Unable to update row. Reason: The UPDATE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK_Product_StandardCost". The conflict occurred in database "AdventureWorksLT", table "SalesLT.Product", column 'StandardCost'.
> The statement has been terminated.

I am getting this error in catch block because I am updating incorrect data in table.

[image]

What I want is to get Column name on particular this constraint fires. Here it would be : **StandardCost**. Is there any way that I can find column name in my C# code?

Comment: you need to parse the exception message

Comment: @Rahul - You mean I need to fetch from exception message by some logic?

Comment: Yup, exactly .. what I mean

Comment: even thought I fetch from the string, what could be the best logic for it? I can think about substring text between last '' (single quote pair). Is it best solution?

Answer (score 2):

A simple `Substring` with `IndexOf` on the exception message:

```
var message = ex.Message;
var column = message.Substring(message.IndexOf("column '") + 8, message.IndexOf("'", message.IndexOf("column '") + 9) - message.IndexOf("column '") - 8);
```

Comment: this is working. But is there anyway to get column name in exception stack? and no need to do this kind of manipulation over message?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: Confirmed.  The error returned from SQL Server contains that string, and there is no built-in API for extracting data from it.